# Kidz-Star tablet that won't save photos onto external sd card

Tags: external-sd

My son's Kidzstar tablet doesn't have any option on the camera where to store photos and videos. The tablet is using 4.0.3. The photos and videos are being stored to internal SD card which it says is full and so can't take any more photos or videos. I bought a 16GB Micro SD Card and mounted it but the device will still not allow me to take photos. Also Apps can only be moved from internal memory to internal SD card with no option for external SD card.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

There are some options. They all most likely start with making some room first by moving the pictures/videos already present on internal storage/internal SD to the external SD. Then:

- use a 3<sup>rd</sup> party camera app supporting to save on external SD. Most of them do. My personal recommendation (very subjective of course) would be [ProCapture Free](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ProCapture-Free/com.neaststudios.procapture.free) (and if you like it, go Pro).
- Try some "advanced App2SD" app from the playstore, which might be able to move (more) apps to the external card. This might require rooting.
- for some devices, there are hacks to "switch" storage locations, i.e. making the device think the external SD card is the internal, and vice versa. They for sure require root.

I would go with the first option. It's the most easy to realize, does not require root, and for sure doesn't have that much potential to "mess things up". You even can make the "new camera app" the default one, or switch back to the stock one anytime.